# How do I actively increment my counter based off of my AJAX results?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am on the final step of my first ajax project. I've made a thumbs up icon that when pressed increments a column in the database via this code:

**HERE IS THE HTML AND JQUERY ON THE VIEWABLE PAGE**

```
<div id="comment_id">+1</div>
<div id="thumb_thumb">                              
    <?php $comment_id = $result['id'];?>
    <a class="myButtonLink" href="Profile_test.php?id=<?php echo $prof->id; ?>" id="<?php echo $comment_id; ?>">Vote Up!</a>
</div>

    <script>
    $('.myButtonLink').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var comment_id = $(this).attr('id');
      $.ajax({ type: 'POST',
               url: 'thumbs.php',
               data: 'comment_id=' + comment_id,
               success: function(data) {
                  alert(data);
                  if(data.result == "error") {
                      alert(data.msg);
                 } else {
                      $('#numvotes').html(data.msg);
                 }
             }
      });
    });        
    </script>
```

**HERE IS THE HIDDEN PHP PAGE IT IS SENT TO**

```
    <?php
     require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
     . '/includes/system/init.php');

     // 1. CHECK AND SEE IF THE
     "$comment_id" IS VALID. I AM GOING TO
     RETREIVE THE VALUE OF THE $_POST BEING
     SENT FROM THE PHP PAGE THAT IS SENDING
     THE REQUEST

     /* QUERY TO CHECK $_POST DATA WITH: */

    /* this is grabbing id that jquery
     sent over via post */
     if(isset($_POST['comment_id'])) {


         /* making a variable out of the
     grabbed id */ $retreived_comment_id =
     $_POST['comment_id'];  


     $query = "UPDATE `CysticAirwaves` SET
     `thumbsUp` = `thumbsUp` + 1 WHERE `id`
     = '" . $retreived_comment_id . "'"; $request =
     mysql_query($query,$connection) ;
     $result = mysql_fetch_array($request);


     }
   ?>
```

So now I just need to be able to dynamically have my counter work when a thumb is clicked and the specified comment is marked a plus one in the db

```
<div id="comment_id">
            +1 //NEED TO MAKE THIS ACTUALLY COUNT
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var currentCount = $('#comment_id').text();

$('#comment_id').text(++currentCount);
```

Comment: so how do I link that to that div? I really new at this, been putting along

Comment: @LightningWrist - what do you mean 'how do I link that div'? #comment_id is referring to the id="comment_id" that you already specified in your html....they are already linked...

Comment: it incremented it to some extent but its actually clashing with my existing code and increment the counter and db differently .It is also breaking my html structure and only increments (incorrectly ) the first comment on the page. I upvoted it though :)

Comment: @light: if it breaks your html it's because `.text` strips every html tags. You need to have a div containing only the number without any tags. `<div id="counter">123</div>`

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things.

1) You need to make sure the POST value an integer and not arbitrary and/or malicious data

```
$retreived_comment_id = filter_var($_POST['comment_id'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
if(!is_int($retreived_comment_id)) {
  echo 'error';
  exit;
}
```

2) It's a good idea to make sure all data is escaped when using user input

```
$query = "
  UPDATE `CysticAirwaves` 
  SET `thumbsUp` = `thumbsUp` + 1 
  WHERE `id` = ".mysql_real_escape_string($retreived_comment_id)."
"; 

$request = mysql_query($query, $connection);
```

3) Return `'success'` on success and `'error'` on failure

```
$request = mysql_query($query, $connection);
if($request) {
  echo 'error';      
} else {
  echo 'success';
}

exit;
```

4) Increment the count using jQuery

```
success: function(data) {
  if(data == "success") {
    var $comment = $('#comment_id');
    $comment.html($comment.text()+1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this line at ajax succes request, instead of alert(data)

```
document.getElementById('comment_id').innerHTML = data;
```

Comment: Using jQuery it should be `$('#comment_id').html(data);`

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you are not returning anything from your PHP code back to ajax.  You need to return an array with at least "msg", and "error" to satisfy your current code on success.  Then create another array element for "success" => 1 if there was no errors.

```
//your php should return your array at the end of your function like this:
return array("msg" => "some message to return", "error" => "some error if you have one", "success" => [1 or 0] );

//ajax function blah blah blah
success: function(data){
    if( data.success == 1 ){
        var currentCount = $("#comment_id").text().substr(1);
        $("#comment_id").text( currentCount+1 );
     }
```